# C# How to split string based on 2 parameters?

Tags: c#

I have three string called `This_is string1` and `This is string2` `There_is string3`

How to split these 3 strings after "This_", "This " "There_) in one condition? basically, i want to split based on first "_" or " " in a string in one condition.

Comment: You can just replace " "  by "_" and yet do just one simple conditional split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple, you can use the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, specifying the multiple delimiters (in your case the underscore and whitespace):

```
str.Split(new char[]{'_',' '})
```

LinQPad result:

[image]

If you want to split only the first part, you can use the 2nd overload of [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
str.Split(new char[]{'_',' '}, 2);
```

and this is the result in LinQPad:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So you want to split only the first part? You can use the overload of [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows to specify the count and multiple delimiters:

```
str.Split(new[]{' ', '_'}, 2);
```

So on the first string you get: `"This"` + `"is string1"`, similar on the others.